# Remove numbers in python string before the number 1

Tags: python, string

I was wondering if it were possible to drop numbers before the number 1 in a string:

```
original_string = 'Word 2 def 1 here 2 what 3 for 4 that'

desired_string = 'Word def 1 here 2 what 3 for 4 that'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def remove_number_before(text, sep='1'):
    words = text.split()
    index = words.index(sep)
    new_words = [item for i, item in enumerate(words) if not (i<index and item.isdigit())]
    return ' '.join(new_words)

words = 'Word 2  def 1 here 2 what 3 for 4 that'

result = remove_number_before(words, '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well:

```
import re

original_string = 'Word 2 def 4 1 here 2 what 3 for 4 that'
if '1' in original_string:
     indexfirst=int(original_string.index('1')) 
else:
     indexfirst=0

original_string=re.sub('[023456789]', '', original_string[0:indexfirst])+original_string[indexfirst:]
print(original_string)
```